# Show Json Object In TextBox

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have json returned from Database.I want to pick only one object Value and show it in the textbox. Here is my json.

```
[{
  "ErrorMessage":"",
  "ID":294,
  "ExpenseID":0,
  "EffectiveDate":"/Date(1262284200000)/",
  "FormattedEffectiveDate":"01-01-2010",
  "Perunit":null,
  "VATRate":17.5,
  "ChangedByID":1,
  "ChangedByName":"superuser, superuser",
  "Expense":null,
  "ErrorSummary":null,
  "ErrorList":[]
 }]
```

I have Tried

```
 var Jsoninvoice = JSON.stringify(data)
 alert(Jsoninvoice.VATRate) and also alert(data.VATRate)
```

Thank you In advance.

Comment: Do you mean you want to show both values in an Alert?  Are you trying to debug the returned data? If so you should be using your browser's debugging tools.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is already json object and `stringify` is not needed as **@tymJV** said you need to parse it if it is returned as string, just you need to access array item, as it is an array:

```
alert(data[0].VATRate)
```

[**SEE FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/ehsansajjad465/c57HG/)

Comment: Apologies - I think we submitted it at the same time!  Didn't mean to repeat your answer.

Comment: @LorenPosen i submitted 23 minutes ago and you have 3 minutes ago

Comment: Not sure what happened, then, because it wasn't there when I started writing the answer.  Again, I apologize.

Comment: Thanks for that.I had data with Objects in array.And i have sent it after stringify the data.So now I got it..it needs data[0].VATRate.Thank you

Answer (score 3):

You have an array containing 1 object. `stringify` turns this object into a string - you need it parsed so you can use it.

(I'm not sure if the object is parsed already, so to cover all bases, we'll parse it)

```
var Jsoninvoice = JSON.parse(data);
alert(Jsoninvoice[0].VATRate);
```

You have to specify the arrays index before you can access the properties.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `$.parseJSON(YOURJSON)`, and then use the keys to pull the data.  Since it's in an array, you'll have to use [0] to pull the first item in the array (ie: your data).

### Example

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var j ='[{"ErrorMessage":"","ID":294,"ExpenseID":0,"EffectiveDate":"/Date(1262284200000)/","FormattedEffectiveDate":"01-01-2010","Perunit":null,"VATRate":17.5,"ChangedByID":1,"ChangedByName":"superuser, superuser","Expense":null,"ErrorSummary":null,"ErrorList":[]}]';
    var json = $.parseJSON(j);
    alert("VATRate: "+json[0].VATRate);
});
```

[Fiddle for reference](http://jsfiddle.net/6xGcN/)

Comment: Thank you too.this is also needful to me to understand JSON behaviour.